# Display the first page of pdf from url in an imageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf

I want to display the first page of a pdf in an ImageView. All I have is the link to the pdf file. I have seen this feature in whatsapp and in many other apps.

Or do we need to convert the first page of the pdf to image and then upload the image along with the pdf to use it in ImageView while displaying.

I have a RecyclerView in which I need to show the list of all the available pdf in the server. While displaying I need to show the first page of available pdf in an ImageView. When the user clicks the imagview the download starts. I have done the RecyclerView part and the downloading part but I don't have an idea how I can show the first page of pdf availabe through link in imageView. Each of the item in RecyclerView should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW2Nm.png).

Comment: Indeed. An ImageView cannot display a pdf document or pages from it.

Answer (score 5):

This code return bitmap pdf first page from file path.

```
       private Bitmap pdfToBitmap(File pdfFile) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(pdfFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
                final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
                if(pageCount>0){
                    PdfRenderer.Page page = renderer.openPage(0);
                    int width = (int) (page.getWidth());
                    int height = (int) (page.getHeight());
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    
                    page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
                    page.close();
                    renderer.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
```

Comment: but I don't have the file. I only have the link to the pdf file.